# A global nextjs middleware without need for import in all the routes

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, middleware

## TLDR;

**a middleware to nextjs like `express` where I only define it once and it'll automatically applies to all of my routes**

I want a middleware style like we have in `express` I'll define a middleware inside the `server.js`(entry file) and the middleware will apply to all the routes without any other work needed. well I need similar thing to NextJs

***these what I've been tried and used for a while***

1: Using High Order Component (HOC):

I don't like this approach because of these drawbacks

- Using **HOC** will disable **fast-refresh** functionality which's is really nice future to have [More Info Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#:%7E:text=Sometimes%2C%20a%20file%20would%20export%20the%20result%20of%20calling%20higher-order%20component%20like%20HOC(WrappedComponent).%20If%20the%20returned%20component%20is%20a%20class%2C%20state%20will%20be%20reset.)
- I have to import my middleware in every api route file which is really not fun to do and wrapping your api files in a function is not a thing to remember all the time

2: using **`next-connect`**

I don't like to use this package due to these drawbacks

- The nextjs ways to handle api routes seem more natural since i use nextjs i want to still use the nextjs way to handle my routes. not totally different style just for sake of a middleware
- same as the `HOC` I don't like to import `nc` and `my-middleware` in every api file

well why not just using a custom server like express? the thing is when i use nextjs I want to only use nextjs also using a custom server will lose so many cool future of nextjs which's is partially why I use nextjs

Comment: To your first point, Fast Refresh doesn't apply to API routes. Short of using a custom server, there's no workaround to having to import the middleware on every API route. I guess you could have a single catch-all API route instead of several ones if you wanted.

Comment: @juliomalves sorry i did not pay attention i'm using HOC for nextjs pages too, so fast-refresh will disable in that case.

Comment: Without HOC not possible, if you have any workaround then please let us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `_app.tsx`, which will run for all pages, though it has some drawbacks too like disabling automatic static generation.

Another option is to implement a custom server using `express` itself, as shown in [this example](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

Comment: using custom  server just have too much drawback really hoped nextjs did not had his own api so we didn't have to choose between them

`A custom server can not be deployed on Vercel, the platform Next.js was made for.`

`Before deciding to use a custom server please keep in mind that it should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet your app requirements. A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic Static Optimization.`